# Angularjs Sub domains

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am hoping someone can help direct me a bit.

I am busy with a Angularjs application. I am using ui-router for routing,
and everything is going pretty well. I have a requirement to implement subdomains.

clients should be able to browse to the site through the normal url, but also 
be able to login via their subdomain, which they would be able to customise the landing page for example. Login and registration is currently working fine, so it is only to add the functionality to handling subdomains. These sub domains will also not be a static list, as companies register, they can choose a subdomain name. Dns is already configured for this, so just the Angular side left.

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Louis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the sub domain will reload your site and there is nothing you can do about that. To figure out which subdomain is being accessed you can use the following code:

```
var segments = location.hostname.split('.');
var subdomain = segments.length>2?segments[segments.length-3].toLowerCase():null;
console.log('Subdomain is', subdomain);
```

Note that from your code's perspective, the sub domain will never change because if it does, it will be reloaded.

Comment: Hi Remento, thank you for your reply. I will give this a try out now and get back to you as soon as I have checked it out. thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: Hi Remento, while I can see that your answer does indeed get the sub domain, I fail to see how I can use this for customising a page. For example when I browse to www.mysite.acme.co.za (just a sample link) I currently have a route that will serve a view for the root.

Now if one of our clients navigates to www.client.mysite.acme.co.za, I would perhaps like to load a template different than the standard home page, and then perhaps fetch data from a database and inject that into the page.

The idea is that clients can have their own branding on their subdomains.

Comment: Calculate the sub domain before defining the route. You can then make the default route conditional on the sub domain. If the fact that it is static os irrelevant as the site will reload if the sub domain changes.

Comment: Hi Remento, thanks again for your quick reply.

I do not intend on changing the sub domain, so I think the reloading will not be a problem, if I understand you correctly.

Would it be too much to ask if you could perhaps show how this route would look when registering routes?

It is really only the home page that would present a different view, the rest of the site would load the views as they are.